# How do I return ignore an empty field when using a javascript web scraper?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I've built a basic scraper using the 'children' command to target the fields. The fields are categorized by category and each category has a varying number of columns. The scraper is set-up with a static number of child commands so there will almost always be non-existent data as some sections will have 20 columns of data, some 3, some 0, etc. How do I add a command to ignore these empty strings?

```
        let cheerio = require('cheerio');

        const request = require('request')
        const fs = require('fs');
        request('https://www.cars-data.com/en/abarth-punto-evo-1.4-t-jet-16v-specs/5', function(error, 
        response, html) {
        if (!error) {
            const $ = cheerio.load(html)
            $('.col-7 > dl').each(function() {
                var children = $(this).children();
                console.log($(children[0]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[1]).text() + ' | ' + 
                $(children[2]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[3]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[4]).text() + 
                ' | ' + $(children[5]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[6]).text() + ' | ' + 
                $(children[7]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[8]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[9]).text() + 
                ' | ' + $(children[10]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[11]).text() + ' | ' + 
                $(children[12]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[13]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[14]).text() 
                + ' | ' + $(children[15]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[16]).text() + ' | ' + 
                $(children[17]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[18]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[19]).text() 
                + ' | ' + $(children[20]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[21]).text() + ' | ' + 
                $(children[22]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[22]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[23]).text() 
                + ' | ' + $(children[24]).text() + ' | ' + $(children[25]).text() + ' | ' + 
                $(children[26]).text());
                });
            }
        })
```

Comment: your question is not clear on what "empty strings" is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$('.col-7 > dl').each(function(i, dl) {
  var children = $(dl).children().get()
  console.log(children.map(c => $(c).text()).join(' | '))
})
```

Comment: pguardiario that was perfect. Thank you very much!